BIND providing different answers to the same query from the same machine (different software)
I am trying to build a lab to replicate an issue we are seeing however have hit a problem.
Setup: Two instances of bind running on different ports on the same server.
Instance A: Configured with a simple RPZ policy that blocks example.com, recursive querying allowed from localhost and any.  [port 54]
Instance B: Configured to use "forward only" with Instance B as the sole forwarder;  [port 55]
Test 1 - expected results
Querying instance A with dig "dig example.com @127.0.0.1 -p54", gets the following (correct results, NXDOMAIN)
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com @127.0.0.1 -p54
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 52665
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 8300a71b26db4dfe0100000067086bb06e4a20d874d17582 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.INA

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
rpz.example.com.60INSOAlocalhost. need.to.know.only. 201702121 60 60 432000 60

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#54(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 11 00:05:04 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 134

and the logs on Instance A show
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119: UDP request
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119: using view '_default'
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119: request is not signed
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119: recursion available
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119 (example.com): query (cache) 'example.com/A/IN' approved
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119 (example.com): try rpz QNAME rewrite example.com via example.com.rpz.example.com
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119 (example.com): rpz QNAME NXDOMAIN rewrite example.com/A/IN via example.com.rpz.example.com
11-Oct-2024 00:07:47.061 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#50119 (example.com): reset client

TEST 2 - incorrect results
Querying instance B with dig "dig example.com @127.0.0.1 -p55", gets the following (incorrect results)
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com @127.0.0.1 -p55
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24269
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 1e0aad6357bd5b840100000067086d59a3953dc8128220a1 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.INA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.1INA93.184.215.14

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#55(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 11 00:12:09 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84

The logs of Instance A show that it is handling the query; but not using RPZ.
11-Oct-2024 00:12:09.757 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#33523: UDP request
11-Oct-2024 00:12:09.757 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#33523: using view '_default'
11-Oct-2024 00:12:09.757 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#33523: request is not signed
11-Oct-2024 00:12:09.757 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#33523: recursion available
11-Oct-2024 00:12:09.757 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#33523 (example.com): query (cache) 'example.com/A/IN' approved
11-Oct-2024 00:12:09.757 client @0x7f8b1c1a1318 127.0.0.1#33523 (example.com): reset client

Test 3 - failure test
Just for thoroughness, if instance A is killed, the queries to instance B fail as expected with SERVFAL, confirming that INSTANCE B is using INSTANCE A not finding a different path.
Can anyone suggest what is going on and how to get Instance A to provide RPZ responses to Instance B?

Perhaps some shared resources are getting corrupted. Anyway, rather than running 2 instances, I would advise you to bring up a couple of vm's instead to ensure separation.

I've moved Instance B over to its own server (Server B) with no change to the above tests.   Using dig from Server B , querying Instance A directly still gets the expected results (RPZ applied). however using dig to query instance B (forwarding to instance A) returns an IP address (no RPZ)
